# Plot 3 vectors in 3d

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 3 vectors , one for angles of `Phi` , another for angles of `Teta` , and the last one a vector of points in the `Y axe` ,after computing the points of `Teta` & `Phi` with a function :

```
for teta = 0 : 10^-2 : pi/2 
    for phi = 0 : 10^-2 : pi/2 
        Y(current) = v*sin(phi)*sin(teta);  
        Teta(current) = teta;
        Phi(current) = phi;
        current = current + 1;
    end
end
```

How can I plot the three of them together ?

I want to plot a `3d` graph with `Teta` & `Phi` as a function of `Y` .
I've tried with `plot3` but the result wasn't so satisfactory .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear about the exact goals, but here's my interpretation:

```
teta = 0:.01:pi/2;
phi =0:.01:pi/2;
[t p]=meshgrid(teta,phi);
Y = v*sin(p)*sin(t);
surf(t,p,Y)
xlabel('teta')
ylabel('phi')
zlabel('1*sin(teta)*sin(phi)')
```

Create vectors of `teta` and `phi` values, use `meshgrid` to produce a matrix of t and p values, and use the vectorized form of `sin` (rather than a `for` loop).  Then use `surf` to plot the results as a surface in 3D.[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This one is ok? I've made step larger and set v as 1.

```
current = 1;
for teta = 0 : 10^-1 : pi/2 
    for phi = 0 : 10^-1 : pi/2 
        Y(current) = 1*sin(phi)*sin(teta);  
        Teta(current) = teta;
        Phi(current) = phi;
        current = current + 1;
    end
end
plot3(Teta,Phi,Y);
xlabel('Teta')
ylabel('Phi')
zlabel('Y')
grid on
```

Comment: Looks great , I've done this myself ,but what I was looking for is maybe using `surf` , however when I did it came out pretty wrong . Is it possible to do the same with surf  ? thanks .