# How to plot a list of vectors as a sphere?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, geometry

I have an array of normalized vectors (1538 of them) forming a sphere. Also I has an array of numbers of the same size 1538. I want to plot something like this:

[image]

I tried the `sphere` and `surf` functions but I can't find a way to use my vectors. I figured there should be some way to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140328/plot-3-vectors-in-3d ?

Comment: Hi. I think I've seen that before. But my problem is that the vectors I have are 3D and I just want the colors to be mapped to the other array of numbers. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [delaunay](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html) to create a triangulation and plot that using [trimesh](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/trimesh.html) or [trisurf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html).

Both trimesh as trisurf accepts a fourth argument to specify the color of each vertex, add the option `'facecolor','interp'` to interpolate the color of each face between vertices.

edit: I experimented a bit further on it, and since it's a sphere, I think [convhull](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) is better suited.

Example:

```
[x,y,z]=sphere(25);
x=x(:);y=y(:);z=z(:);

tri = convhull([x y z]);
C = cos(y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z,C,'facecolor','interp');
```

[image: trisurf_colored]

instead of `C` in the example you can use your own vector of values to specify the color

Comment: did it in my test code, removed it here because it doesn't add very much to it

Comment: Yes, convhull is correct. The surface of a delaunay tessellation is the convex hull, but the tessellation is a 3-d thing that trisurf does not use anyway.