# How to draw Geosphere in matlab?

Tags: matlab, geometry, surf

How to draw a Geosphere in matlab?

By `Geosphere` I mean the way of discretization points on a sphere (Geosphere is, for example in 3Ds Max).

On the image below, it is shown `Sphere` (on the left) and `Geosphere` (on the right)
[image]

In Matlab there is a function `sphere`, which gives such a result:
[image]

I need to get such an image of a Geosphere. I have a matrix Nx3, with xyz coordinates of every point of Geosphere.

**UPDATE:**

I had problem only with displaying (drawing) geosphere, because I already have data - xyz coordinates of every point. Thats why `Gunther Struyf`'s answer helped me and I accepted it.

This I got with such way of displaying: (Geosphere of factor = 6, N=362)
[image]

How to get 3d points of geosphere? I used free library [SPHERE_GRID](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/sphere_grid/sphere_grid.html) to get points of 3d-sphere. (In library there are different ways of discretization sphere).

Also, for calculating points of Geosphere, thanks `@Rody Oldenhuis` for answer below.

Comment: now I'm interested on how you built that point array :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have the points, I think you can use the same solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12853620/1162609):

```
tri = convhull(xyz);
trisurf(tri,xyz(:,1),xyz(:,2),xyz(:,3));
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a function lying around here that is able to generate a triangulation of the sphere up to arbitrary precision. It's a function I've based on `buildsphere` by Giaccari Luigi, who sadly has disappeared off the internet completely (along with this function).

So, I'll post it here, and on my File Exchange account. Once that gets approved, I'll replace this code with a link.

Note that I have some pre-generated models on my computer, on which this function depends. You'll have to remove that section before you can run it.

For plotting the generated sphere: see Gunther Struyf's answer.

```
function [p, t] = TriSphere(N, R)
% TRISPHERE: Returns the triangulated model of a sphere using the
% icosaedron subdivision method.
%
% INPUT:
% N (integer number) indicates the number of subdivisions,
%   it can assumes values between 0-inf. The greater N the better will look
%   the surface but the more time will be spent in surface costruction and
%   more triangles will be put in the output model.
%
% OUTPUT:
% In p (nx3) and t(mx3) we can find points and triangles indexes
% of the model. The sphere is supposed to be of unit radius and centered in
% (0,0,0). To obtain spheres centered in different location, or with
% different radius, is just necessary a traslation and a scaling
% trasformation. These operation are not perfomed by this code beacuse it is
% extrimely convinient, in order of time perfomances, to do this operation
% out of the function avoiding to call the costruction step each time.
%
% NOTE:
% This function is more efficient than the matlab command sphere in
% terms of dimension fo the model/ accuracy of recostruction. This due to
% well traingulated model that requires a minor number of patches for the
% same geometrical recostruction accuracy. Possible improvement are possible
% in time execution and model subdivision flexibilty.
%
% EXAMPLE:
%
%  N=5;
%
%  [p,t] = TriSphere(N);
%
%  figure(1) axis equal hold on trisurf(t,p(:,1),p(:,2),p(:,3)); axis vis3d
%  view(3)

% Author: Giaccari Luigi Created:25/04/2009%
% For info/bugs/questions/suggestions : giaccariluigi@msn.com
% ORIGINAL NAME: BUILDSPHERE
%
% Adjusted by Rody Oldenhuis (speed/readability)

    % error traps
    error(nargchk(1,1,nargin));
    error(nargoutchk(1,2,nargout));
    if ~isscalar(N)
        error('Buildsphere:N_mustbe_scalar',...
            'Input N must be a scalar.');
    end    
    if round(N) ~= N
        error('Buildsphere:N_mustbe_scalar',...
            'Input N must be an integer value.');
    end

    % Coordinates have been taken from Jon Leech' files

    % Twelve vertices of icosahedron on unit sphere
    tau = 0.8506508083520400; % t   = (1+sqrt(5))/2, tau = t/sqrt(1+t^2)
    one = 0.5257311121191336; % one = 1/sqrt(1+t^2)  (unit sphere)    
    p = [
        +tau  +one  +0     % ZA
        -tau  +one  +0     % ZB
        -tau  -one  +0     % ZC
        +tau  -one  +0     % ZD
        +one  +0    +tau   % YA
        +one  +0    -tau   % YB
        -one  +0    -tau   % YC
        -one  +0    +tau   % YD
        +0    +tau  +one   % XA
        +0    -tau  +one   % XB
        +0    -tau  -one   % XC
        +0    +tau  -one]; % XD

    % Structure for unit icosahedron
    t = [  
         5  8  9 
         5 10  8 
         6 12  7 
         6  7 11 
         1  4  5 
         1  6  4 
         3  2  8 
         3  7  2 
         9 12  1 
         9  2 12 
        10  4 11 
        10 11  3 
         9  1  5 
        12  6  1 
         5  4 10 
         6 11  4 
         8  2  9 
         7 12  2 
         8 10  3 
         7  3 11 ];

    % possible quick exit
    if N == 0, return, end

    % load pre-generated trispheres (up to 8 now...)
    if N <= 8
        S = load(['TriSphere', num2str(N), '.mat'],'pts','idx');
        p = S.pts; t = S.idx; 
        if nargin == 2, p = p*R; end
        return
    else
        % if even more is requested (why on Earth would you?!), make sure to START 
        % from the maximum pre-loadable trisphere
        S = load('TriSphere8.mat','pts','idx');
        p = S.pts; t = S.idx; clear S; N0 = 10;
    end

    % how many triangles/vertices do we have? 
    nt = size(t,1); np = size(p,1); totp = np;    
    % calculate the final number of points    
    for ii=N0:N, totp = 4*totp - 6; end    
    % initialize points array
    p = [p; zeros(totp-12, 3)];

    % determine the appropriate class for the triangulation indices
    numbits   = 2^ceil(log(log(totp+1)/log(2))/log(2));
    castToInt = ['uint',num2str(numbits)];

    % issue warning when required
    if numbits > 64
        warning('TriSphere:too_many_notes',...
            ['Given number of iterations would require a %s class to accurately ',...
            'represent the triangulation indices. Using double instead; Expect ',...
            'strange results!']);
        castToInt = @double;
    else
        castToInt = str2func(castToInt);
    end

    % refine icosahedron N times
    for ii = N0:N
        % initialize inner loop
        told  = t;
        t = zeros(nt*4, 3);
        % Use sparse. Yes, its slower in a loop, but for N = 6 the size is
        % already ~10,000x10,000, growing by a factor of 4 with every
        % increasing N; its simply too memory intensive to use zeros().
        peMap = sparse(np,np); 
        ct    = 1;        
        % loop trough all old triangles        
        for j = 1:nt

            % some helper variables
            p1 = told(j,1);
            p2 = told(j,2);
            p3 = told(j,3);
            x1 = p(p1,1); x2 = p(p2,1); x3 = p(p3,1);
            y1 = p(p1,2); y2 = p(p2,2); y3 = p(p3,2);
            z1 = p(p1,3); z2 = p(p2,3); z3 = p(p3,3);

            % first edge
            % -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

            % preserve triangle orientation
            if p1 < p2, p1m = p1; p2m = p2; else p2m = p1; p1m = p2; end

            % If the point does not exist yet, calculate the new point            
            p4 = peMap(p1m,p2m);
            if p4 == 0
                np = np+1;
                p4 = np;
                peMap(p1m,p2m) = np;%#ok
                p(np,1) = (x1+x2)/2;
                p(np,2) = (y1+y2)/2; 
                p(np,3) = (z1+z2)/2;
            end

            % second edge
            % -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

            % preserve triangle orientation
            if p2 < p3; p2m = p2; p3m = p3; else p2m = p3; p3m = p2; end

            % If the point does not exist yet, calculate the new point
            p5 = peMap(p2m,p3m);
            if p5 == 0
                np = np+1;
                p5 = np;
                peMap(p2m,p3m) = np;%#ok
                p(np,1) = (x2+x3)/2; 
                p(np,2) = (y2+y3)/2; 
                p(np,3) = (z2+z3)/2;
            end

            % third edge
            % -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

            % preserve triangle orientation
            if p1 < p3; p1m = p1; p3m = p3; else p3m = p1; p1m = p3; end

            % If the point does not exist yet, calculate the new point            
            p6 = peMap(p1m,p3m);
            if p6 == 0
                np = np+1;
                p6 = np;
                peMap(p1m,p3m) = np;%#ok
                p(np,1) = (x1+x3)/2; 
                p(np,2) = (y1+y3)/2;
                p(np,3) = (z1+z3)/2;                
            end

            % allocate new triangles
            %   refine indexing
            %          p1
            %          /\
            %         /t1\
            %      p6/____\p4
            %       /\    /\
            %      /t4\t2/t3\
            %     /____\/____\
            %    p3    p5     p2            
            t(ct,1) = p1; t(ct,2) = p4; t(ct,3) = p6; ct = ct+1;            
            t(ct,1) = p4; t(ct,2) = p5; t(ct,3) = p6; ct = ct+1;
            t(ct,1) = p4; t(ct,2) = p2; t(ct,3) = p5; ct = ct+1;            
            t(ct,1) = p6; t(ct,2) = p5; t(ct,3) = p3; ct = ct+1;

        end % end subloop
        % update number of triangles
        nt = ct-1;         
    end % end main loop

    % normalize all points to 1 (or R)
    p = bsxfun(@rdivide, p, sqrt(sum(p.^2,2)));
    if (nargin == 2), p = p*R; end
    % convert t to proper integer class
    t = castToInt(t);    

end % funciton TriSphere
```